# Escape issue in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .net, escaping

I trying to escape the code below:

```
<div class="col-xs-12"><img class="blog-img img-responsive" src="{%CurrentDocument.GetValue("StoryImageURL")#%}" /></div>
```

Tried Like below :

```
<div class="col-xs-12"><img class="blog-img img-responsive" src="{%CurrentDocument.GetValue("'StoryImageURL'")#%}" /></div>
```

But not working. Could you please help?

try the below code

```
<div class="col-xs-12"><img class="blog-img img-responsive" src="{%CurrentDocument.GetValue("StoryImageURL")#%}" /></div>
```

in [this url](http://www.html.am/html-editors/html-text-editor.cfm)

if you flip source button, you can see the source code is altered because of wrong escape

Comment: Could you share what you have tried ?

Comment: its already there in my question  second one is one that i tried

Comment: Try `(\"StoryImageURL\")`

Comment: Ok was not clear ^^ try something like this : `<div class="col-xs-12"><img class="blog-img img-responsive" src="{%CurrentDocument.GetValue(\"StoryImageURL\")#%}" /></div>`

Comment: try the same in this url  http://www.html.am/html-editors/html-text-editor.cfm  if you flip source button, you can see the source code is altered because of wrong escape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<div class="col-xs-12"><img class="blog-img img-responsive" 
    src='{%CurrentDocument.GetValue("StoryImageURL")#%}' /></div>
```